# Updating form fields based on drop down menu selection using AJAX and PHP

Tags: php, ajax, json

I've found tutorials to update form elements with set data and also to show table based on the drop down selection. BUT, I still can't figure out how to merge these two things together.
As it says in the title - I need to update form fields based on the selection from drop down menu.
So far, I've came to this:

**HTML:**

```
<html>
<head profile="http://www.w3.org/2005/20/profile">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Test</title>

<script>

function showUser(str)
{
  var strURL="getUser2.php?user="+str;
  http('GET', strURL, ajax_response, document.form1);
}

function ajax_response(data) {
  for(var key in data) {
    document.form1[key].value = data[key];
  }
}

</script>

</head>
<body>


<div style="margin:30px 500px">

<form name="form1">
<select name="users" onchange="ajax_request()" value="showUser(this.value)">
<option value="">new</option>
<option value="1">First</option>
<option value="2">Second</option>
<option value="3">Third</option>
<option value="4">Fourth</option>
</select>
<br />
<br />
  ID <input type="text" id="ID"><br>
  name <input type="text" id="name"><br>
  city <input type="text" id="city"><br>
</form>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
$user=$_GET["user"];

$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("pophelper", $con);

$sql="SELECT * FROM phonebook WHERE ID = '".$user."'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$ID=$row['ID'];
$names=$row['names'];
$city=$row['city'];

require_once "json/JSON.php";
$json = new Services_JSON();

$value = array("ID" => $ID, "names" => $names, "city" => $city);
$output = $json->encode($value);

print($output);

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

I've tried separately to run PHP file, and it gave the correct result. But when I run it from html, fields just remain empty no matter which option I choose.

Did I miss something? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where is function `http` defined?

Comment: ...and the function `ajax_request()`?

Comment: Honestly... I don't know. This is my first website with ajax.
As I understand - I load the html page, and than from that page a request is sent to the php page, which should return the value that the html page should show in form fields.
But http function - I really don't know about that

Comment: what's this Services_JSON? Why use that when php has json_encode() built-in since v5.2?

Comment: I used that service because I've found it in one of the working examples (though that example did not have possibility to send data according to which an sql query would be made, but rather only set data that is always returned)